# Remove Package and dependencies installed along with it

Tags: linux, command-line, package-management, yum, dependencies

I noticed while removing httpd package that dependencies installed all not removed along with that

```
# yum remove httpd
```

How can i remove a package and dependencies which were installed along with that without affecting other services, like if some dependencies are being used by other services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 yum autoremove
```

will remove any unneeded dependencies from your system.
You need to add `clean_requirements_on_remove=1` to yum.conf